# How to connect 12 SATA 3 disks to a server with GA-790XTA-UD4 board

Tags: storage, sata

How can I connect 12 SATA 3 disks to a motherboard that has just two SATA 3 connectors. What  solution would you recommend?

Comment: Why did you skip reading our FAQ? The first couple of lines says we don't do home IT stuff and where does? lazy!

Comment: And don't just edit the word 'home' to 'office' either - we see all that, read the FAQ please before posting again.

Comment: Not to mention purchase recommendations are off topic anywhere on SE

Comment: @Chopper3 ok, fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how serious you are about physical data loss protection. I use a LSI MegaRAID SAS9280-16i4e (16+4 connectors) at home with a RAID 6 configuration. Those controllers have great protection features, speed and perfect OS support, but cost a lot of money. But my last data loss cost me more than 5 times as much...

As an extra, I suggest buying the Battery Backup Unit. For extra speed and security.